# Handling form submit event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, @class = "form-vertical login-form", id = "loginform" }))

                    <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right">
                        Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                    </button>

}
```

And this the javascript handling the event function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#loginform").submit(function () {
                alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                return false;
            });
}
```

However this doesn't work at all.

the alert is never triggered

Comment: Look at the generated source and you will be enlightened.

Comment: Since you know there is only one form, just use `$("form").submit(...);`

Comment: @ShadowWizard, and what makes you think that there's just one form?

Comment: @Darin good point, was used to old concepts after quick look saw that it's common to have more than one form in MVC. So in my previous comment it should be "In case you have only one form, just use...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal, you never assigned your form an `id` or a `class`. Look at the generated HTML in your browser to understand what I mean.

You are using a completely wrong overload of the `BeginForm` helper.

Try this instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-vertical login-form", id = "loginform" }))
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right">
        Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
    </button>
}
```

Now please read about the different [`BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492719%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overloads on MSDN and compare [`yours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) with [`mine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

As you can see there's a difference between the `routeValues` parameter and the `htmlAttributes` parameter.